# QGraphicView not maximized in complete layout

Tags: qt, qt4

I have following GUI having four `QGraphicView` objects 
[image]

It have four toolbuttons as you can see under each view. To maximize a view I connected toolbutton's signal to hide slot of other three views and set size policy to expanding for all four views. But it is working well only with View1 and View 4 other view are showing following result:

[image]

I am using grid layout. View2 is leaving gap at left hand side and View3 at right. I am not getting any reason why View 2 and View 3 are leaving gap when I am hiding remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works for me under both Qt 4 and Qt 5. It leverages the State Machine Framework to simplify the management of state transitions. The states with one view visible are a substate of the state with no views shown. This gets rid of the need for explicit signal-slot connections and for having to keep lists of views and buttons.

The `State` class is there for debugging purposes only, to visualize state transitions.

Alas, there's a bug (race?) at least in Qt 4.8.5 that makes property assignments not always work properly with nested states. When nested states with overlapping properties are used, sometimes all views and buttons will be hidden in spite of the machine having entered the correct state. There's a workaround for this in the code below.

Note that the grid widget must not have any other widgets with row/column span != 1. If it did, the spacing around hidden widgets would still be visible. This is why I've used two nested layouts.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QStateMachine>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QPointer>

static const int N = 4;
static QPointer<QPlainTextEdit> logView;

class State : public QState
{
public:
    explicit State(const QString& name, QState* parent = 0) : QState(parent) {
        setObjectName(name);
    }
protected:
    virtual void onEntry(QEvent*) {
        QString state = objectName();
        QState* parent = this;
        while ((parent = parent->parentState()) && !parent->objectName().isEmpty() )
        {
            state = parent->objectName() + "->" + state;
        }
        logView->appendHtml(QString("<font color=\"green\">Entering state: <b>%1</b></font>").arg(state));
    }
    virtual void onExit(QEvent*) {
        QString state = objectName();
        QState* parent = this;
        while ((parent = parent->parentState()) && !parent->objectName().isEmpty() )
        {
            state = parent->objectName() + "->" + state;
        }
        logView->appendHtml(QString("<font color=\"red\">Exiting state: <b>%1</b></font>").arg(state));
    }
};

class Widget : public QWidget {
public:
    explicit Widget(bool qt4) {
        QGridLayout *vert = new QGridLayout(this);
        QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
        layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        logView = new QPlainTextEdit;
        logView->appendPlainText(QString("Qt %1").arg(QT_VERSION_STR));
        vert->addLayout(layout, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        vert->addWidget(logView, 1, 0, 1, 1);
        QStateMachine * const machine = new QStateMachine(this);
        machine->setObjectName("machine");
        State * const all = new State("all", machine);
        State * const none = new State("none", machine);
        QList<QState*> ones;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++ i) {
            const QString label = QString("View %1").arg(i+1);
            ones << new State(label, none);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++ i) {
            QState *one = ones[i];
            QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
            QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);
            scene->addText(one->objectName());
            view->setScene(scene);
            layout->addWidget(view, 2*(i/2), i%2, 1, 1);
            QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(one->objectName());
            layout->addWidget(button, 2*(i/2)+1, i%2, 1, 1);
            button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
            all->assignProperty(view, "visible", true);
            all->assignProperty(button, "visible", true);
            if (qt4) {
                // Workaround for a bug: properties in nested states are
                // sometimes not set correctly, so we explicitly set all properties
                // in one state.
                foreach (QState* s, ones) {
                    s->assignProperty(view, "visible", s == one);
                    s->assignProperty(button, "visible", s == one);
                }
            } else {
                none->assignProperty(view, "visible", false);
                none->assignProperty(button, "visible", false);
                one->assignProperty(view, "visible", true);
                one->assignProperty(button, "visible", true);
            }
            all->addTransition(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), one);
            one->addTransition(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), all);
            if (!none->initialState()) none->setInitialState(one);
        }
        machine->setInitialState(all);
        machine->start();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w(QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0));
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```